# Disable collectstatic command when deploying Django App to Azure via Github

Tags: django, azure, github, azure-storage

This is an error that has been giving me countless problems and unfortunately, there is no documented way around it.

I have a Django APP that is running on Azure. I push local changes to Github and through Github actions, the changes are synced to Azure. This has been going on well without any trouble with the build/Deploy processing succeeding.

Trouble came when I created a storage account for the media files and static files on Azure using django-storages[Azure]. So, everytime I pushed changes from localhost to Github, the build/deploy process from Github to Azure will run and manage to run the collectstatic command which unfortunately fails due to unknown error. Running collectstatic from SSH terminal on my Azure portal succeeds albeit after taking like forever, So, I am assuming that it is because of the process taking long that ends up failing.

I do not need this process to run every time I make changes to the site because I can do so from the SSH terminal when there is a need.

I have read from the documentation and most of them recommend setting the value DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 1 to disable the process. However, I don't know how to do that or where to set the value. I tried checking it on the `workflows file` but nothing like that exists. This is troubling me since I am unable to update the website since every change I make locally fails to deploy because of the error.

Here are my settings for the azure storage account:

```
# Media Storage Location
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_azure.AzureMediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'

STATIC_LOCATION = "static"
MEDIA_LOCATION = "media"

AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "my_storage_account"
AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIA_LOCATION}/'

# CORS SETTINGS
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = os.getenv('CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS', True) == 'True'

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://mywebsite.com",
]
```

And this is the custom Azure file:

```
import os
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage

class AzureMediaStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name = os.environ['STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME'] # Must be replaced by your <storage_account_name>
    account_key = os.environ['STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY'] # Must be replaced by your <storage_account_key>
    azure_container = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
    expiration_secs = None

class AzureStaticStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name = os.environ['STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME'] # Must be replaced by your storage_account_name
    account_key = os.environ['STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY'] # Must be replaced by your <storage_account_key>
    azure_container = 'static'
    expiration_secs = None
```

Here is the snippet or the error code that I get:

[image: Error as a result of running collectstatic]

Kindly help on disabling `collectstatic` function during deployment.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, it didn't work. Is there a specific place to put it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. As suggested by Sumithran, adding `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = True` to settings didn't solve the problem. However, I managed it by adding the variable `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = True` to environment variables via configuration settings in the Azure app's home. I also checked the checkbox showing that this was a deployment setting. This saved my day and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Configuration settings, click on New Application setting, and set the name as `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC` then set the value as `True`

That solves it.